# Ipad ShareKit's UIActionsheet Issue

Tags: ipad, sharekit

The Sharekit's initial UIActionsheet displays the items Email, Twitter and Facebook and Cancel on Iphone

However the same code ported to Ipad now the Cancel option is missing on its UIActionsheet.

why is that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using the action sheet in a popover? The standard dismiss interaction for a popover is touching outside of it. There is rarely a "cancel" button in a popover action sheet, and Apple's HIG recommends against it.

Comment: Oh yeah, the default is if touching outside to dismiss the popover.